# How to get the same output on each training iteration of neural network?

Tags: time-series, lstm, keras

I'm a neural network noob and am trying to use LSTM(Keras,Tensorflow backend) for predicting time series data. Every time I train the network, I get a very different set of output values even though the percentage error is around the same.

I'm using adam optimizer and mse loss.

I believed that the inspite of the initial random weights the neural network was supposed to converge to around the same values every time it is trained. Is that belief wrong?

Edit:
I've fixed seeds using `random.seed()`, `np.random.seed()` and `tf.random.seed` and followed the instructions laid out [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development) as well. Still different results. I'm going to try with the theano backend to see whether that works or not. But my main question is, shouldn't the models give similar results in spite of initial randomness.

Comment: You need to use `random.seed(some_number)` to reproduce your research. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do

Comment: I've done all that. Used `random.seed`, `np.random.seed()`, `tf.set_random_seed()`, set the PYHASHSEED value to 0. I still get variability.

Comment: You probably missed some point to set. You need to debug it. Let's compare all initial values from 3 consecutive experiments and you should see the difference.

Comment: Okay, I just ran the model, and the problem seems to be with the importing. I wrote all the neural network code in one file and imported that file, and that is where the problem is. If I run the original file I get reproducible results. Any idea how to fix that?